# Build an array as a tree structure from an XML file

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read this xml file, but the code I am trying to make should work for any xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<auto>
    <binnenkant>
        <voorkant>
            <stuur/>
            <gas/>
        </voorkant>
        <achterkant>
            <stoel/>
            <bagage/>
        </achterkant>
    </binnenkant>
    <buitenkant>
        <dak>
            <dakkoffer>
                <sky/>
                <schoen/>
            </dakkoffer>    
        </dak>
        <trekhaak/>
        <wiel/>
    </buitenkant>
</auto>
```

I am using the two functions below to turn the XML-file into an array and turn that array into a tree.
I am trying to keep the parent-child relationship of the XML file. All I am getting back from the second function is an array with all the tags in the xml-file.

Can someone please help me?

```
function build_xml_tree(array $vals, $parent, $level) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($vals as $item) {
        if (($item['type'] == "open") || $item['type'] == "complete") {
            if ($branch && level == $item['level']) {
                array_push($branch, ucfirst(strtolower($item['tag'])));
            } else if ($parent == "" || $level < $item['level']) {
                $branch = array(ucfirst(strtolower($item['tag'])) => build_xml_tree($vals, strtolower($item['tag']), $level));
            }
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}

function build_tree ($begin_tree, $content_naam) {
    $xml = file_get_contents('xml_files/' . $content_naam . '.xml');
    $p = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $vals, $index);

    ?>
    <pre>
    <?php
    print_r($vals);
    ?>
    </pre>
    <?php

    $eindarray = array_merge($begin_tree, build_xml_tree($vals, "", 1));

    return $eindarray;
}
```

Comment: have you ever heard about [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: Is there a function I could use in DOMDocument?

Comment: a `DOMDocument` object already represents a tree

Comment: I have been looking into DOMDocument for the past couple of hours, but I still haven't found a way to put my xml TAGS into a tree. Puting values into a tree is very easy, yes. But what I need is the tags.

Comment: just for clarify: your requirement is to have an array structured like a tree with the keys made by the nodes tag name?

Comment: Yes, is this posible with a DOMDocument methode?

Comment: please consider to [edit] your answer in order to remove the linked images and insert the text of your XML and PHP. It isn't considered a good practice to put image of your code in SO. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many classes which can load an XML file. Many of them already represent the file in a tree structure: [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is one of them.

It seems a bit strange that you want to make a tree as an array when you already have a tree in a `DOMDocument` object: since you'll have to traverse the array-tree in some way... why don't you traverse directly the tree structure of the object-tree for printing for example?

Anyway the following code should do what you're asking for: I've used a recursive function in which the array-tree is passed by reference.
It should be trivial at this point to arrange my code to better suit your needs - i.e. complete the `switch` statement with more `case` blocks.

- the `$tree` array has a numeric key for each node level
- the tag node names are string values
- if an array follows a string value, it contains the node's children
- any potential text node is threated as a child node

---

```
function buildTree(DOMNode $node = NULL, &$tree) {

    foreach ($node->childNodes as $cnode) {

        switch($cnode->nodeType) {
            case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
                $tree[] = $cnode->nodeName;
                break;
            case XML_TEXT_NODE:
                $tree[] = $cnode->nodeValue;
                break;
        }

        if ($cnode->hasChildNodes())
            buildTree($cnode, $tree[count($tree)]);
    }
}

$source ='the string which contains the XML';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$doc->loadXML($source, LIBXML_NOWARNING);

$tree = array();
buildTree($doc, $tree);

var_dump($tree);
```

Comment: yes, this solve the issue when you have 2 or more consecutive nodes with the same name when the second key would overwrite the previus value: *if an array follows a string value, it contains the node's children* the "string value" is the parent's tag

Comment: This almost solves my problem, the only thing that is missing is that a parent needs to be an array, not a string. The children of these parents need to be put into that array.

Comment: I think it's better you provide the XML input and the expected array output in your question if the above doesn't fit your needs

Comment: the tags as array-keys was my 1st approach but didn't worked since same tags at the same level overwrote the previous key

Comment: It does fit my needs, I just had to change a few things in the way I displayed bij tree in php before it looked the way I wanted it to. Again thank you so much for your help.